# Problem with AggregateResult

Tags: aggregate

My Rolluputility:

```
public class RollUpSummaryUtility { 
//the following class will be used to house the field names
//and desired operations
public class fieldDefinition {
    public String operation {get;set;}
    public String childField {get;set;}
    public String parentField {get;set;}

    public fieldDefinition (String o, String c, String p) {
        operation = o;
        childField = c;
        parentField = p;
    }
}

public static void rollUpTrigger(list<fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions,
list<sObject> records, String childObject, String childParentLookupField,
String parentObject, String queryFilter) {

    //Limit the size of list by using Sets which do not contain duplicate
    //elements prevents hitting governor limits
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();

    for(sObject s : records) {
        parentIds.add((Id)s.get(childParentLookupField));
    }

    //populate query text strings to be used in child aggregrator and
    //parent value assignment
    String fieldsToAggregate = '';
    String parentFields = '';

    for(fieldDefinition d : fieldDefinitions) {
        fieldsToAggregate += d.operation + '(' + d.childField + ') ' +
        ', ';
        parentFields += d.parentField + ', ';
    }

    //Using dynamic SOQL with aggergate results to populate parentValueMap
    String aggregateQuery = 'Select ' + fieldsToAggregate +
    childParentLookupField + ' from ' + childObject + ' where  ' +
    childParentLookupField + ' IN :parentIds ' + queryFilter + ' ' +
    ' group by ' + childParentLookupField;

    //Map will contain one parent record Id per one aggregate object
    map<Id, AggregateResult> parentValueMap =
    new map <Id, AggregateResult>();

    for(AggregateResult q : Database.query(aggregateQuery)){
        parentValueMap.put((Id)q.get(childParentLookupField), q);
    }

    //list of parent object records to update
    list<sObject> parentsToUpdate = new list<sObject>();

    String parentQuery = 'select ' + parentFields + ' Id ' +
     ' from ' + parentObject + ' where Id IN :parentIds';

    //for each affected parent object, retrieve aggregate results and
    //for each field definition add aggregate value to parent field
    for(sObject s : Database.query(parentQuery)) {

        Integer row = 0; //row counter reset for every parent record
        for(fieldDefinition d : fieldDefinitions) {
            String field = 'expr' + row.format();
            AggregateResult r = parentValueMap.get(s.Id);
            //r will be null if no records exist
            //(e.g. last record deleted)
            if(r != null) {
                Decimal value = ((Decimal)r.get(field) == null ) ? 0 :
                    (Decimal)r.get(field);
                s.put(d.parentField, value);
            } else {
                s.put(d.parentField, 0);
            }
            row += 1; //plus 1 for every field definition after first
        }
        parentsToUpdate.add(s);
    }

    //if parent records exist, perform update of all parent records
    //with a single DML statement
    if(parentsToUpdate.Size() > 0) {
        update parentsToUpdate;
    }

}
```

}

My Trigger:

```
// Recap de cumul des affaires liés à une mission

Trigger MissionrollupAffairesTotale on Affaire__c (after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete) {

//unique Parent Object Ids
set<Id> MissionIds = new set<Id>();
//hold list of Missions Record to be update
private  List<Mission__c>  MissionListUpdatable = new List<Mission__c>();

/**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE ****/

list<Affaire__c> AffaireDossier = new list<Affaire__c>();
list<Affaire__c> AffaireFormation = new list<Affaire__c>();

for(Affaire__c r : trigger.new) {
            if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Dossier') {
                AffaireDossier.add(r);
            }
            if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Formation') {
                AffaireFormation.add(r);
            }            
 }

 /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE ****/

if(AffaireDossier.size() > 0) {

//Cumul de montants d'affaire dossiers gagnée 

if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =  new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c', 'Dossiers_vendus__c'),
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c','Nbre_de_Dossiers_vendus__c')
  };



RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
  }

//Cumul de montants d'affaire dossiers en cours 
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Dossiers_en_cours__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Dossier_en_cours__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c',  'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\'  and Etape__c <>\'Annulée\' and  Etape__c <>\'Perdue\' and  Etape__c <>\'Gagnée\'');
  }


//Cumul de toutes les affaires dossiers confondues
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_Affaires_Dossier__c')
 };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c','and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\'');
  }

//Cumul de montants d'affaire Formation gagnée
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Formations_vendues__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Formations_vendues__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
}

//Cumul de montants d'affaire Formation en cours 
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Formation_en_cours__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Formations_en_cours__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c',  'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'  and Etape__c <>\'Annulée\' and  Etape__c <>\'Perdue\' and  Etape__c <>\'Gagnée\'');
}


//Cumul des affaires de type Formation total
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
 };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.new,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c','and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'');
   }
}

// FIN DES CREATION, UPDATE, RECUP



// Cumul des effacements d'affaires Dossier gagnées
if(trigger.isDelete){

 /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE EFFACEMENT****/

list<Affaire__c> AffaireDossierd = new list<Affaire__c>();
list<Affaire__c> AffaireFormationd = new list<Affaire__c>();

for(Affaire__c r : trigger.old) {
            if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Dossier') {
                AffaireDossierd.add(r);
            }
            if(r.Type_d_affaire__c == 'Formation') {
                AffaireFormationd.add(r);
            }            
 }

 if(AffaireDossier.size() > 0) {

 /**** POPULATE LISTS D'AFFAIRE EFFACEMENT****/


list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Dossiers_vendus__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Dossiers_vendus__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c','and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
 }

 // Cumul des effacements d'affaires Dossier en cours
if(trigger.isDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Dossiers_en_cours__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Dossier_en_cours__c')
 };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\'  and Etape__c <>\'Annulée\' and  Etape__c <>\'Perdue\' and  Etape__c <>\'Gagnée\'');
}

 // Cumul des effacements d'affaire Dossier totale 
if(trigger.isDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_Affaires_Dossier__c')
 };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Dossier\'');
      }
    }

// Idem qu'au dessus si effacement Formation vendues
if(trigger.isDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Formations_vendues__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_de_Formations_vendues__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c','and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\' and Etape__c = \'Gagnée\'');
 }

 // Idem qu'au dessus si effacement Formation en cours
if(trigger.isDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('SUM', 'Montant__c',
 'Formation_en_cours__c'),
  new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
  };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'  and Etape__c <>\'Annulée\' and  Etape__c <>\'Perdue\' and  Etape__c <>\'Gagnée\'');
 }

// Idem qu'au dessus si effacement nbre de Formation 
 if(trigger.isDelete){
list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions =
 new list<RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition> {
 new RollUpSummaryUtility.fieldDefinition('COUNT', 'Montant__c',
 'Nbre_Affaires_Formation__c')
 };
RollUpSummaryUtility.rollUpTrigger(fieldDefinitions, trigger.old,
 'Affaire__c', 'Mission_affaire__c','Mission__c', 'and Type_d_affaire__c = \'Formation\'');
    }    

 }
```

My Test:

```
@isTest
 private class TestMissionrollupAffairesdossier {
 static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
//Profile pf ='00e20000001GlJM';//
 //[Select Id from Profile where Name = 'System Administrator']//

 User u = new User();
 u.FirstName = 'Test';
 u.LastName = 'User';
 u.Email = 'testuser@test123456789.com';
 u.CompanyName = 'test.com';
 u.Title = 'Test User';
 u.Username = 'testuser@test123456789.com';
 u.Alias = 'testuser';
 u.CommunityNickname = 'Test User';
 u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Mexico_City';
 u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
 u.EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1';
 u.ProfileId = '00e20000001GlJM';
 u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
 insert u;

 // Création d'un compte pro

  system.runAs(u){
Account acc = new Account();
acc.RecordTypeId='012200000006EEH';
acc.Name='PRO';
acc.Activit_principale__c='Biomasse';
acc.SIREN__c='123456789';
acc.Phone ='0122112211';
 insert acc;


 // Création d'un compte fédérateur
   system.runAs(u){
Account accf = new Account();
accf.RecordTypeId='012200000006EEC';
accf.Name='Federateur';
accf.Activit_principale__c='Biomasse';
accf.SIREN__c='111222333';
accf.Phone ='0122112222';
 insert accf;

  // Création d'une Operation
 system.runAs(u){
 Operation__c opp = new Operation__c();
 opp.Name='TEST';
 opp.Federateur__c=accf.Id;
 insert opp;

   // Création d'une Mission
 system.runAs(u){
Mission__c mi = new Mission__c();
mi.Name = 'NE RIEN INSCRIRE';
mi.Operation__c=opp.Id;
mi.Statut__c='Non démarré';
mi.Statut_de_diagnostic__c='Non contacté';
mi.Pro__c=acc.Id;
insert mi;

  // Création d'une affaire dossier gagné
system.runAs(u){
 Affaire__c aff = new Affaire__c();
 aff.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
 aff.Etape__c ='Gagnée';
 aff.Type_d_affaire__c='Dossier';
 aff.Compte__c=acc.Id;
 aff.Mission_affaire__c=mi.Id;
insert aff;

  // Création d'un produit de l'affaire Dossier gagnée
 system.runAs(u){
Produit_affaire__c pdt = new Produit_affaire__c();
pdt.Famille__c = 'Dossier';
pdt.Type_de_produit__c = 'Dossier Initial + mention EE (Dossier)';
pdt.Quantite__c=1;
pdt.Montant__c = 400;
pdt.Affaire__c=aff.Id;
insert pdt;

  // Création d'une affaire dossier en cours
system.runAs(u){
 Affaire__c aff1 = new Affaire__c();
 aff1.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
 aff1.Etape__c ='Offre émise';
 aff1.Type_d_affaire__c='Dossier';
 aff1.Compte__c=acc.Id;
 aff1.Mission_affaire__c=mi.Id;
insert aff1;

  // Création d'un produit de l'affaire Dossier en cours

 system.runAs(u){
Produit_affaire__c pdt1 = new Produit_affaire__c();
pdt1.Famille__c = 'Dossier';
pdt1.Type_de_produit__c = 'Dossier Initial + mention EE (Dossier)';
pdt1.Quantite__c=1;
pdt1.Montant__c = 400;
pdt1.Affaire__c=aff.Id;
insert pdt1;


//// Création d'une affaire Formation gagnée

 Affaire__c aff2 = new Affaire__c();
aff2.Name = 'Test Opportunity1';
aff2.Etape__c ='Gagnée';
aff2.Type_d_affaire__c='Formation';
aff2.Compte__c=acc.Id;
aff2.Mission_affaire__c = mi.Id;
 insert aff2;


//Création d'un produit de l'affaire Formation gagnée

Produit_affaire__c pdt2 = new Produit_affaire__c();
pdt2.Famille__c = 'Formation';
pdt2.Type_de_produit__c = 'Formation fédérateur';
pdt2.Quantite__c=1;
pdt2.Montant__c = 300;
pdt2.Affaire__c=aff2.Id;
insert pdt2;


//// Création d'une affaire Formation en cours
Affaire__c aff3 = new Affaire__c();
aff3.Name = 'Test Opportunity2';
aff3.Etape__c ='Offre émise';
aff3.Type_d_affaire__c='Formation';
aff3.Compte__c=acc.Id;
aff3.Mission_affaire__c = mi.Id;
 insert aff3;

//Test Produit de l'Affaire on insert
Produit_affaire__c pdt3 = new Produit_affaire__c();
pdt3.Famille__c = 'Formation';
pdt3.Type_de_produit__c = 'Formation fédérateur';
pdt3.Quantite__c=1;
pdt3.Montant__c = 800;
pdt3.Affaire__c=aff3.Id;
insert pdt3;

//Test Affaire on second insert
 Affaire__c aff4 = new Affaire__c();
aff4.Name = 'Test Opportunity2';
aff4.Etape__c ='Gagnée';
aff4.Compte__c=acc.Id;
aff4.Mission_affaire__c = mi.Id;
 insert aff4;

//Test Produit de l'Affaire on insert
Produit_affaire__c pdt4 = new Produit_affaire__c();
pdt4.Famille__c = 'Formation';
pdt4.Type_de_produit__c = 'Formation fédérateur';
pdt4.Quantite__c=1;
pdt4.Montant__c = 800;
pdt4.Affaire__c=aff4.Id;
insert pdt4;

//Test Affaire dossier
AggregateResult ag1 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c  where Type_d_affaire__c='Dossier' and Etape__c ='Gagnée' and Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id ];
Mission__c ou3 = [select Dossiers_vendus__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
system.assertEquals(ou3.Dossiers_vendus__c ,ag1.get('expr0'));

// AggregateResult ag3 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c where Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id];
//Mission__c ou5 = [select Formations_vendues__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
//system.assertEquals(ou5.Formations_vendues__c,ag3.get('expr0'));

// AggregateResult ag5 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c where Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id];
//Mission__c ou7 = [select Formation_en_cours__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
//system.assertEquals(ou7.Formation_en_cours__c,ag5.get('expr0'));

//Test Affaire on delete
delete aff;
AggregateResult ag2 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c  where Type_d_affaire__c='Dossier' and Etape__c ='Gagnée' and Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id ];
Mission__c ou4 = [select Dossiers_vendus__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
system.assertEquals(ou4.Dossiers_vendus__c,ag2.get('expr0'));

//AggregateResult ag4 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c where Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id];
//Mission__c ou6 = [select Formations_vendues__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
// system.assertEquals(ou6.Formations_vendues__c,ag4.get('expr0'));

//AggregateResult ag6 = [select sum(Montant__c) from Affaire__c where Mission_affaire__c = :mi.Id];
//Mission__c ou8 = [select Formation_en_cours__c from Mission__c where Id = :mi.Id];
 //system.assertEquals(ou8.Formation_en_cours__c,ag6.get('expr0'));

}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

*My Error*:

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a0211000003U3FZAA0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   MissionrollupAffairesTotale: execution of AfterDelete
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Trigger.MissionrollupAffairesTotale: line 15, column 1: [] Trace de
>   pile  Class.TestMissionrollupAffairesdossier.myUnitTest: line 175,
>   column 1

Can someone help me work out what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you understand the error ?

Comment: In fact I m not developper, it very new for me I'm consultant, and I need to make some developpement and want to understand to make some trigger. Could you help

Answer (score 2):

I think line 15 is:
for(Affaire__c r : trigger.new) {

In a "delete" trigger there are no new records, only old records. So Trigger.new is null.

Looks like you've correctly used Trigger.old for the rest of the trigger.isDelete conditional code.

Comment: I put if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){ at the beginning, and changed the AffaireDossierd.add (line 122) into AffaireDossier.add. Now the error is Too many SQL queries.

Comment: @Dahan 2 Things can help you resolve the Too many SQL queries. 1. Use Test.StartTest() and Test.Stop Test to reset the soql limits. 2. Instead of creating 1 object at a time, build up a list of them and insert them all at once. More info on the Test.Start/Stop: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm